# Docker-compose rails postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've been following [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application) to 'dockerize' my rails application and have hit a snag with connecting to the db after some searching around, no solutions seem to work.  I've also tried the default user 'postgres' and no password, but still no luck.  My error indicates that my password is incorrect, but everything I try doesn't change the error:

```
web_1       | I, [2017-06-02T00:58:29.217947 #7]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:3000 fd=13
postgres_1  | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "web"
postgres_1  | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
web_1       | E, [2017-06-02T00:58:29.230868 #7] ERROR -- : FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "web"
```

Here's what I have:

### .env

```
LISTEN_ON=0.0.0.0:3000
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://web:mypassword@postgres:5432/web?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.4 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends
ENV INSTALL_PATH /web
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . .

# precompile assets using dummy data
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname SECRET_TOKEN=pickasecuretoken assets:precompile
VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]
VOLUME /postgres
CMD RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.4.5
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: web
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

web:
  build: .
  links:
    - postgres
  volumes:
    - .:/web
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  env_file:
    - .env
```

### config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

The line in `database.yml` grabs the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable that is stored in the container from the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the better part of a day fiddling with this. What finally worked for me was to fall back to the Postgres defaults.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
 image: postgres:9.4.5
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"
 volumes:
   - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

#### .env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://web:@postgres:5432/web?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000
```

In the `DATABASE_URL`, keeping the password separator in the url but leaving the password blank finally made it work.